# .NET MAUI .csproj MSBUILD

Tags: .net, build, msbuild, maui, csproj

When I am developing my MAUI application and I press build. The build process runs for all platforms (I am on windows).
But what I want to achieve is build specific to emulator and configuration I have chosen, to speed things up.

I develop mobile app for android and iOS but sometimes I test it on Windows and my colegues on MAC.

So for release it is simple:

```
<PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)' == 'Release'">
    <TargetFrameworks>net6.0-android;net6.0-ios</TargetFrameworks>
</PropertyGroup>
```

but for Debug we currently have just:

```
<PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)' == 'Debug'">
    <TargetFrameworks Condition="$([MSBuild]::IsOSPlatform('windows'))">$(TargetFrameworks);net6.0-windows10.0.19041.0</TargetFrameworks>
    <TargetFrameworks Condition="$([MSBuild]::IsOSPlatform('osx'))">$(TargetFrameworks);net6.0-maccatalyst</TargetFrameworks>
</PropertyGroup>
```

What we want to achieve is build specific to current debug emulator/machine that is specified up here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/8dnxY.png

So in case we have chosen

- windows machine https://i.stack.imgur.com/16XIe.png
- developing on windows
- then build just for Windows TargetFramework

on the other hand

- if we have android emulator chosen: https://i.stack.imgur.com/WM9sz.png
- developing on windows
- then build just for Android TargetFramework

Is something like this even possible ?
Yes, I could theoretically temporarily comment out those frameworks I dont want to build for, but I would rather solve it the MSBUILD way.

Answer (score 0):

> But what I want to achieve is build specific to emulator and configuration I have chosen, to speed things up.

You can right click on .csproj and then click Properties. In Application, uncheck the platform you don't want to build. It will automatically comment out those frameworks you don't want to build for.

Comment: Interesting, I didnt know about this option. But it doesnt comment it out but it removes it from the .csproj file. Nevertheless, it doesnt serve the purpose I wanted to achieve. Because I could achieve the same thing by commenting it out. But aplying some rules(condition) into .csproj that only specific framework should be built based on chosen emulator(environment) would be more effective. But still, I dont know if something like that is even possible.

Comment: @ssamko However, if you check the platform you unchecked before, it will automatically appear again which was removed it from the .csproj file before.